# Python 3 Selenium | Clipboard not working on headless chromedriver on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, clipboard, emoji, headless-browser

In StackOverflow, there is already a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751960/selenium-python-headless-chrome-not-copying-to-clipboard) about this topic. Though the OP of the post answered stating that "*this is a bug in Windows*" and that "*I did not find a solution, I just cut part of my code out*".

I have a slightly different circumstance. I cannot cut the part of the code out but I can use different web browsers.

**My Circumstance:**

I need to write a specific text into a text box. Unfortunately, the text I am writing includes few instances of *emojis*, thus `send_keys()` was not an option. Instead, with the help of StackOverflow, I end up using `pyperclip.copy(text)` and `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')` which works fine (it successfully copied the emojis).

But I also need the ChromeDriver to be `--headless`. Everything worked well, except for the copy-paste part.

**My question**

My question is: how should I tackle this issue?

- Web browser must be hidden (ex. `--headless` at ChromeDriver)
- it can write *emojis* into a text element
- has to work on Windows OS (Windows 7 - 10)

Comment: The clipboard is a service/daemon provided by the window manager, not a feature in Chrome. So if you are running headless, there might not be a system clipboard available.

Comment: @HåkenLid Hmm, do you know of any alternative solution to my issue? (writing emojis into a textbox element, while having the web browser 'hidden')?

Comment: Is using a different browser driver an option? I think the Firefox selenium driver should support characters beyond the BMP in `send_keys`.

Comment: @HåkenLid It is an option. I will try it then.

Comment: @HåkenLid the firefox selenium driver (`geckodriver`) did not work. Not only it was not able to send the emoji via send_keys but my code also got this [issue #1184](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1184).

Comment: @HåkenLid ok, after further testing I can confirm that *firefox selenium driver does support emoji send_keys*. However, I still cannot confirm that it works on headless mode and mainly, my code got into multiple issue (since it was coded with `ChromeDriver` in mind. So I am still open to other suggestions.

Comment: There's an open issue about this in chromium, so it might get fixed in the future.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269

Comment: @HåkenLid so after long process of refactoring the code to make it compatible with Firefox web driver, I manage to successfully run my program. But even though it 'solved' my issue, there are a lot of limitation to using firefox driver so if you want, you can put it as an answer but I will accept it if nobody else can think of another alternative solution :)

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner Does `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')` works in Firefox headless mode?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue so I used klembord instead of pyperclip.

https://pypi.org/project/klembord/

```
# pip install webdriver-manager
# pip install klembord
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import klembord
klembord.init()
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
print("Headless Firefox Initialized. Wait for output")
driver.get("https://www.lipsum.com")
l = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/p")
klembord.set_text(l.text) # setting text to clipboard
print("Check clipboard by pressing WIN + V or CTRL +V")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I have tried with Klembord but I had the same issue described in the main post,

Comment: Hi @Vikram, I have done what is explained in the Klembord page:
>>> import klembord
>>> klembord.init()
>>> klembord.get_text()
............ When I do this, pastes my computer clipboard content but not the "copy" command content from the headless browser.

Comment: What is the source of the text that u want to copy? Is it directly from html tag or any python variable?

Comment: @sunny9495 Can u post ur error or anything that helps to solve it?